# No spacing between cells in a grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'd like to know how i can remove the spacing between cells in a grouped UITableView.
I tried googling for it and saw some similar SO questions that referred similar queries. I tried returning heightForHeader and heightForFooter as 0.0 (programmatically and in IB) but it did not work.
Any suggestions? I've attached an image of how i'd like it to look.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition, set `sectionHeaderHeight` and `sectionFooterHeight` of the tableView to 0 and replace the background view of the cell. The remaining few pixels between sections is part of the default grouped background view. You can see this by replacing the background view with a UIView with a white backgroundColor.

Comment: I tried setting sectionHeaderHeight and sectionFooterHeight to 0 and it still did not work. I then realized that the background PNGs i'm using for the cells has a transparent border which gave it the appearance of spacing between the two cells. wish i'd have realized that earlier!

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you just want to have all your cells with rounded corners. You do not need to use grouped table view, enough to define custom background view for cells like :

```
NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image_with_rounded_corners" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIEdgeInsets imInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
UIImage *strImage = [theImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:imInset];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:strImage];
cell.backgroundview = cellBackgroundView;
```

similar way u need to define selectedBackgroundView

......

cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellSelectedBackgroundView;